# Windows 7/10 explorer: Is this a bug, or intended behavior?

Tags: windows-7, windows-10, windows-explorer, rename, selection

In Explorer in Windows 7, if you select 9 or more files (but not all) and rename them, the selection is lost after the files are renamed. Is this intended, or a bug? This behavior does not show in XP. The same bug shows in Windows 10.

I'm surprised that I cannot find this mentioned anywhere.

**Edit:** *When I posted the question, my pre-release version of W10 did not have the bug, but the release version does.*

Comment: Are you renaming them anything in particular? Are there more than the files being selected in the folder?

Comment: I have noticed this behavior for years, so I have used many different kinds of names. And you are right, it doesn't happen when renaming all files in the folder. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @MartinArgerami: Weird, never noticed it but then again I never use the in-built bulk rename feature because it's so limited. This certainly looks like a bug to me, to go along with the long list of Explorer bugs.

Comment: [Another reason to use a utility](http://www.bulkrenameutility.co.uk/Main_Intro.php)

Comment: @Moab: that's very nice, but if I'm not wrong it requires launching a different program. For many of my needs the built-in functionality is good enough, and I can quickly work from the folder I'm using.